# How to run a php file with javascript in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a html with some javascript in in, now I want to run another php-file (test.php) without showing or opening this file. It's part of a loop and I tried:

```
for(i = 1; i < length; i++){
        var bname = table.rows[i].cells.item(0).innerHTML;  
        var bvalue = table.rows[i].cells.item(1).innerHTML;             
        location.href = "test.php?account="+account+"&key="+key+"&memo="+memo+"&bname="+bname+"&bvalue="+bvalue;
    }
```

But this will redirect the current location and runs only once...
I also tried to use:

```
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();                             
        xmlhttp.open("POST","test.php?account="+account+"&key="+key+"&memo="+memo+"&bname="+bname+"&bvalue="+bvalue);
        xmlhttp.send();
```

But that seems not to work.
I also found the hint to use ajax, but I never used it and don't know how to pass my variables to test.php.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ajax is the way to go. Btw, ajax is the same as `xmlhttp` just with a fancier syntax from jQuery. Even if you enver used it, while google you'll find tons of examples. Its one of the most used technologies for communication between JS and PHP and even here on stackoverflow you'll find 1000 of people who had asked about it and got good answers. Just look for those ;)

Comment: XMLHttpRequest and ajax are quite the same thing. It should work though: did you check your browser console/dev tools? do you see the requests in the network tab?

Comment: Do you know jQuery for example? Take a look at it here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

You can do using ajax,

```
$.post("test.php",
    {
        account: account,
        key: key,
        memo:memo,
        bname:bname,
        bvalue:bvalue
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
```

Comment: Thats for your help. Looks like it worked partially. PHP-Code is executed but variables don't get posted. Another javascript code on the test.php isn't executed aswell but I think this is because javascript is clientside, am I right with that?

Comment: You need to setup PHP to work with POST (for this answer here to work) or with GET. Make sure PHP is setup correctly to work with this ajax method! Make a simple NEW test1.php and inside, have simple if looking for `$_POST['account']`. Now pass test value into account via ajax and do a comparason check via PHP to make sure it worked! Echo something via php and it will show via alert box from ajax if all worked! If you echo "Worked!" the data that comes back from ajax should show "Worked!".

Comment: What is the output of print_r($_POST); in test.php ?

Answer (score 0):

use ajax to send data from javascript to a php file

```
vars="account="+account+"&key="+key+"&memo="+memo+"&bname="+bname+"&bvalue="+bvalue;
    var ajaxhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "test.php";
        ajaxhr.open("POST", url, true);
        ajaxhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        ajaxhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxhr.readyState == 4 && ajaxhr.status == 200) {
                var return_data = ajaxhr.responseText;

            }
        }
        ajaxhr.send(vars);
```

Answer (score 0):

**I am posting this for a detailed answer to help PHP and Javascript side.**

I would use **jQuery** + **AJAX**. **Reference**: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Ajax is great for sending data to php, reading data from php etc..

Please take time to look at my reference to read up on how it all works for future knowledge!

Lets get into the code!

**Ajax (Javascript - Client Side):**

```
var memoData = "Today is beautiful"; //Varible passed for ajax data
$.ajax({
    url : '/LocationToTestPHP/test.php', //Location to PHP File
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST', //Type of method - Remove this line for GET if required
    data: {account: "Welcome", key: "ValueHere", memo: memoData, bname: "ValueHere", bvalue: "ValueHere"} //Data to send to PHP
}).done(function(data) 
{
    //We check if PHP sent us back the correct data required here.
    if(data == "Success")
    {
        alert("Success! Data returned is: " + data);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Error! We didnt get correct data back. Data: " + data);
    }
});
```

Please note, i provided a variable into ajax data for `memo`, this is
also possible.

**PHP (Server Side) - test.php:**

```
<?PHP
//Check for our value and return data
if($_POST['account'] == "Welcome") //Check if account has Welcome passed in..
{
    echo "Success";
}
else //Welcome is not provided
{
    echo "Account did not equal to Welcome :(";
}
?>
```

I quickly typed this up so hopefully you get the correct idea! Any help required, comment below :)